# Equality in distribution for quantities involving empirical and regular quantile functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

Let $U_1,...U_n$ be i.i.d. random variables of uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and $X_1,...X_n$ i.i.d. real random variables with common cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F$ and empirical cdf $F_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{X_i \leq t}$. Denote by $G_n$ the empirical cdf of $U_1,...U_n$. I don't understand why  we have the following equalities in distribution :

$$F^{-1}\left(G_n^{-1}\right)\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}F_n^{-1}$$ $$F_n^{-1}\left(F^{-1}\right)\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}G_n$$
where $F^{-1}(u)=\inf \left\{ t  \in \mathbb{R}, F(t) \geq u\right\}$ is the quantile function related to $F$, same for $F_n^{-1}$ and $G_n^{-1}$.

Comment: What the first expression seems to be saying intuitively is that if you take a random sample size $n$ from $[0,1]$, represented by $G_n^{-1}$, and apply the inverse cdf $F^{-1}$ to these numbers then you get a random sample from the distribution,  represented by $F_n^{-1}$.  That makes sense

Comment: Can you clarify if $F$ is assumed to be continuous (but not necessarily strictly increasing)? For possibly discontinous $F$ it seems like we could only derive some weak inequalities instead of equalities.